# How do I fix my computer key configuration after using robot.keyPress()?

Tags: java, keypress, keyevent, awtrobot

I have been using the `java.awt.Robot` class (especially *pressKey()* method) in my code.
However, once my code terminates, my keys get reconfigured. In my case, I had *robot* press *Ctrl* and *R*. Afterwards, my key functions for *Start* and *Escape* switched roles. And that was just one of several switches.

What is the fix to this?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because this function only press the key and not release it.
You must call robot.keyRelease(); once after calling keypress() or call it for all the keys when closing the application.

Comment: Thank you. That helps a lot.